# Making a UIView outlet in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, iboutlet

I have almost lost what's left of my sanity today ladies and gentelmen. Interface Builder is about to take it away.
I am new in iOS dev and going through a book right now with all kinds of different tasks.
What I am trying to do is to call a view using a double tap. This isn't about gesture recognizer and the taps, it is purely about the outlet.

1) I have a xib file, where a small menu is drawn.
2) Upon a double tap gesture I want this menu to come out.

This is the way I got it working for me:

```
- (void)displayPanel:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.window.frame.size.height-100, self.window.frame.size.width, 90);
    NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"colorMenuView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *colorView = [nibContents lastObject];
    [colorView setFrame:frame];
    [self.window addSubview:colorView];
    [self.window setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

A nice little menu is drawn at the bottom.

But I want to do that not with the `NSBundle`'s last object, I don't think it is a good approach. I want to do this by making an outlet connection to the UIView that holds my menu.

(I would've posted some pictures but I haven't got enough reputation yet)

When I try to make a connection I can't, the outlet isn't highlighting

When I change the Class of the View from `UIView` to `CustomView` I can connect the subviews, such as labels and buttons, which does seem to be how it should work. I still cannot connect the view though.

Now I add another standard view to the IB. And try to make a connection. It works! And if I try to connect the Custom View, it doesn't.

Now I change the Custom View back to standard. Neither of views can be connected.

Ok lets change one of the views to the Custom and connect another one. It works.

Let's do the implementation of another way of calling the menu now:

```
- (void)displayPanel:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, self.window.frame.size.height-100, self.window.frame.size.width, 90);
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"colorMenuView" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *menu = self.menuView; // the outlet
self.menuView.frame = frame;
[self.window addSubview:menu];
[self.window setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I have no errors for the chunk above. But the menu is still not shown. And it's nil, so it was never actually initiated.

Please help me to understand 2 things:
1) why IB does what it does?
2) why is the menu I finally got connected is nil?

Answer (score 0):

In your second sample you set `owner` param of `loadNibNamed` to be `self`, but doesn't seem to have properly configured `File's owner` placeholder in the xib file. This results in nil outlet reference.

You should setup `File's owner` placeholder of `colorMenuView` xib to be an instance of specific class, eg. `ColorMenuViewController` (using Identity inspector). This will let you connect `view` outlet of used view controller with your top level view. This view can be then loaded using one of following approaches:

```
// 1
ColorMenuViewController* vc = [[ColorMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"colorMenuView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIView* colorView = vc.view;

// 2
ColorMenuViewController* vc = [ColorMenuViewController new];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"colorMenuView" owner:vc options:nil];
UIView* colorView = vc.view;
```

Your base class, which implements gesture recognizer actions, can be used as the `File's owner` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Zakol! I have thought about making another ViewController and I think I should be able to make it working that way. But do you think it is possible to do it without a view controller? Just a CustomView calling a UIView?